# How to copy a file out of the project with cx_freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm interested in copying a file from my project to the CX_Freeze folder, with the include_files method you can bring files to your project, but I do not know how to do it to bring it out.

I generate an .exe installer, which installs the program in Program Files, and manually I have to copy a file to a specific directory, I would like to be able to do it at the same time it is installed.

In short, what I want to do is copy from **`my_project/path/to/archive`** to **`C:\Windows\SysWOW64`**

I share my setup that I have so far

**setup.py**

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform == 'win32' else None

import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Users\puig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Users\puig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tk8.6"

shortcut_table = [
    ("DesktopShortcut",           # Shortcut
     "DesktopFolder",             # Directory_
     "ScannerApp Connector",      # Name
     "TARGETDIR",                 # Component_
     "[TARGETDIR]connector.exe",  # Target
     None,                        # Arguments
     None,                        # Description
     None,                        # Hotkey
     None,                        # Icon
     None,                        # IconIndex
     None,                        # ShowCmd
     'TARGETDIR'                  # WkDir
     )
    ]
msi_data = {'Shortcut': shortcut_table}
bdist_msi_options = {'data': msi_data}

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'include_files': [
            'my_project/GUI/templates',
            'my_project/GUI/images',
            'my_project/agent/config.cfg',
            os.path.join(sys.base_prefix, 'DLLs', 'sqlite3.dll'),
            os.path.join(sys.base_prefix, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
            os.path.join(sys.base_prefix, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
        ],
        'packages': [
            'PyQt5.uic',
            'PyQt5.QtGui',
            'PyQt5.QtWidgets',
            'PyQt5.QtCore',
            'PIL',
            'zmq',
            'os',
            'tkinter',
            'raven',
        ],
        'excludes': [
            'django',
            'Image',
            'PyQt5.Qt',
        ],
    },
    'bdist_msi': bdist_msi_options,
}

executables = [
    Executable(script='my_project/GUI/GUI.py', base=base),
    Executable(script='my_project/agent/connector.py', base=base)
]

setup(
    name='x',
    version='0.2.9a0',
    description='description',
    options=options,
    executables=executables,
    author='x',
    license='MIT',
    skip_build=True
)
```

Any ideas?

Thx.